# no hover action on transparent area of png images html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, png, transparent

i have a png image on my webpage and it's shape is diamond, so the four corners of the image are transparent...

whenever i hover on image i made it move left and top by -10px

```
#one{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:-234px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

#one:hover{
    top:0px;
    left:-244px;
    -webkit-filter:opacity(0);
}
```

all i want to do is not to move image by hovering on transparent area...

is it possible... i want to use css or javascript...
i dont know jquery so if you tell me jquery ans please tell me how to link it in my html page...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding an additional element positioned in front of the image that is rotated 45 degrees, and then use that element for the hover action.

That will enable you to move the image only when the diamond shape is hovered over.

Please note that without additional logic this will only work in modern browsers that support CSS3 transforms (Webkit, Mozilla and IE10).

```css
#one-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#one{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#one-action{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50px 50px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50px 50px;
    transform-origin: 50px 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#one-action:hover,
#one-action:hover + #one{
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one-wrapper">
  <span id="one-action"></span>
  <img id="one" src="image-url.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Update the top/left positions as required.

Comment: i like your suggestion but actually this was only one problem.. i have more 4 more shapes and they are little different than diamond (imagine diagonal from topleft of square to bottom right and the bottom left portion is filled leaving the corner little bit...)

Comment: Oh ok - so that solution does not really help! I do not think there is a way to dynamically 'ignore' the transparent parts of an image with HTML/CSS. You could use a custom image `<map>` element but again this would require custom parameters for each different image... Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: sad :( but is there any way to create a shape using javascript it has solid color in it and only 4 corners... can we create it by using javascript and move 10px on mouse hover....

Comment: HTML markup (shaped by CSS or Javascript alike) is inherently rectangular in nature, so any shape with 4 corners is usually do-able. However it is probably outside the scope of these comments to explain all the options. I suggest you take a look at all the CSS3 transform properties available [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) and see if (like the rotate property used above) you can use them to mold/skew the `<span id="one-action"></span>` element into the required shape for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a background of div and apply hover pseudo class to that div.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#one {
  position:relative;
  top:10px; 
  left:-234px; 
  float:left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  background:url(__path_of_image__);
}
#one:hover {
  top:0px; 
  left:-244px; 
  -webkit-filter:opacity(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is [HTML Image maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map) (which was created for such purposes), and if you really don't like that for some reason you can also go with [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG).

Comment: i have used image mapping and i guess it is for creating links... i want to move the shape smoothly(webkit transition) on hover...